# MVC Submit not editting a property of the model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I got a strange issue.
When I'm trying to edit an object in mvc, just one of the object's properties is not changing, all the other properties gets their new values.

I'm using EF with repositories and unit of work.

This is the object:

```
public partial class License
    {
        public int LicenseID { get; set; }
        public string Lic_LicenseRequest { get; set; } // <-- this is the problematic  property
        public int Lic_LicenseMaxClientsNum { get; set; }
        public string Lic_LicenseComments { get; set; }
     }
```

This is the controller:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
{
    LicenseModel model = new LicenseModel();
    model.License = unit.LicenseRepository.GetObjectById(id);

    if (model.License == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(LicenseModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        unit.LicenseRepository.EditObject(model.License);
        unit.Save();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    LicenseModel newModel = new LicenseModel();
    newModel.License = unit.LicenseRepository.GetObjectById(model.License.LicenseID);
    return View(newModel);
}
```

This is the View:

```
@model MySystem.UI.MVC.Models.LicenseModel
<body>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
    <legend>License</legend>

       @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.License.LicenseID)

       <div class="form-group">
          @Html.LabelFor(model => model.License.Lic_LicenseMaxClientsNum)
          @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.License.Lic_LicenseMaxClientsNum)
          <p class="help-block">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.License.Lic_LicenseMaxClientsNum)</p>
       </div>

       <div class="form-group">
          @Html.LabelFor(model => model.License.Lic_LicenseRequest)
          @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.License.Lic_LicenseRequest)
          <p class="help-block">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.License.Lic_LicenseRequest)</p>
       </div>

        <div class="form-group">
           @Html.LabelFor(model => model.License.Lic_LicenseComments)
           @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.License.Lic_LicenseComments)
           <p class="help-block">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.License.Lic_LicenseComments)</p>
        </div>

<p>
   <button type="submit" value="Save">Save</button>
</p>

</fieldset>
}
</body>
```

I want to be clear that I didn't bring here all the properties for the License object beacuse it's a lot. But I use ViewModel beacuse some of the properties require dropdownlist (and I'm not usind ViewBag or ViewData).

I tried to put directly in the database a temporary string for the property, but the it doesn;t show any value at all.

I'm thinking that it might be beacuse I added this property a while after loading the db to the EF and to the VS project. I did refresh the EF of course, but it might not success.
How can I be sure that the property in the EF and project is comunating correctly with the db? What else could be the problem? (again, all the other properties are correctly modified).

Comment: from the controller to the database, and just the certain property that I said

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like I suspect, unfortunately the EF refresh was not successfully made, so I refresh the hole EF from the databse and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you have used Repository and Unit Of Work patterns; one more logical step would be using EF context with a per request life time (not Session, not Application, but Request). This way you do not have to refresh EF much, which is not a good thing in a web app.

Db Context will be disposed at the end of request life time (one experience: do not call SaveChanges at that point, but at a logical point in your app; preferably in your service class).

Unity dependency injection library already has a MVC bootstrapper that will provide you control over your injected object life time.

[This](http://genericunitofworkandrepositories.codeplex.com/) library implemented a generic Repository pattern alongside Unit Of Work and has a video to how put things together in a MVC app. I've used it and enjoyed it.